# Which version of Mongodb-plugin is compatible with Grails 2.2.4?

Tags: mongodb, grails, plugins

I'm trying to fix the problem with

> > com.mongodb.DBPortPool$ConnectionWaitTimeOut: Connection wait timeout after 120000 ms

and read, that in plugin version `:mongo:3.0.0` the issue should be fixed by now.

In my app I'm using Grails 2.2.4 and mongo 1.3.3 now. In plugin-doc stands, that mongo 3.0 works only with Grails 2.3.x.

My question is, which is the most recent mongo plugin version to support Grails 2.2.4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongodb 2.0.1 version.

Shashank